# Server Socket implementation in J2ee server

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services

I am building a server client based application, in which server will be based on server-socket implementation where client shall exchange information in a continuous connection.
Now that i want to implement that; i only find J2EE based implementations, where we can deploy WAR files on the server( Similar to PHP servers).
How and where can i host my java socket based application that shall give console based output.......

I even tried on AWS, but couldn't find a clue.There also in elasticbeanstalk i can implement J2EE based WAR file which is servlets.. i want class file direct implementation and running....

Comment: just make a normal application :)  public static void main(String args[])

Comment: I think one reason for deploying a core java application as WAR might be that we want a 'managed application'. Any ideas on how to achieve this without creating a WAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As djb suggested you can write a simple Java application that do not need the Servlet Container (like Tomcat) to run.

You should read the official Oracle tutorial about socket.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

This is a sample code:

```
public class DateServer {

    /**
     * Runs the server.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date().toString());
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```